# python code should perform SJF algorithm but it's not

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

consider the following code which takes inputs (Burst & arrival) times of the processes and sort them according to sjf algorithm, but the output is wrong, he order the process in other algorithm let's name it first processes entered by the user so any help ?

```
Processes = input("   Enter the  processes times & arrival times separated by a comma: ")


   BurstTimes = Processes[::2]
    ArrivalTimes = Processes[1::2]
    print '   Burst Times:', BurstTimes, '\n', '   Arrival Times', ArrivalTimes,'\n',
    list1, list2 =  BurstTimes, ArrivalTimes

    indices1 = range(len(list1))
    indices1.sort(key=lambda x: list1[x])
    list1 = map(lambda i: list1[i], indices1)
    labelled = zip(list1, ascii_uppercase)
    sorted_data = sorted(labelled, key=itemgetter(0)) 
    labels = [pair[1] for pair in sorted_data]
```

Comment: YES It's the same code but with small changes to do SJF

Comment: So... what's the input, the output you get and the output you're expecting? Your code seems to be sorting by burst time, which is correct for SJF; what's the problem?